Configure SSL Certificate on websphere server
I have the Java method:
String xmlRespuesta = "";
        
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            InputStream keyStoreStream = new FileInputStream(Constantes.FICHEROP12);
            keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, Constantes.PASSWORDP12);
            
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, Constantes.PASSWORDP12).build();
            
            HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(final String hostname, final SSLSession session) {
                    // TODO Apéndice de método generado automáticamente
                    return hostname.equals(Properties.getLexnetHostname());
                }
            };
            
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    sslContext, new String[] {"TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1"}, null,
                    hostnameVerifier);
            
            HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(Properties.getLexnetProxy(), 8080);
            
            RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setProxy(proxy)
                    .build();
            Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                    .register("https", sslsf)
                    .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                    .build();
            
            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager =
                    new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
            
            try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                    .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                    .build()) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Properties.getLexnetUrlEndpoint() + Constantes.OBTENERPENDIENTESGENERAL);
                httpPost.setHeader("SOAPAction", "");
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");

                StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(soapXml);
                httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
                xmlRespuesta = EntityUtils.toString(client.execute(httpPost).getEntity(), "UTF-8");

And on the line keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, Constantes.PASSWORDP12); error occurs:

[9/05/24 12:22:19:827 CEST] 000000c0 SystemErr     R java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
[9/05/24 12:22:19:827 CEST] 000000c0 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.crypto.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
[9/05/24 12:22:19:827 CEST] 000000c0 SystemErr     R  at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1456)

It must be from the local Server since it works correctly in a shuttle class.
I would like to know how to configure an SSL certificate to Websphere Server v9. I have two certificates: one public (extension .cer) and another private (extension .p12 with his password).
Can somebody help me?
Thanks
